# React project html files

Tags: reactjs

guys,  I'm new to ReactJS and just wanted to clarify some things about
React projects structure.

should every react project includes only one main HTML page? which we will control some inner container using the main App.js file?
If one can recommend about a good documentation about this issue it will be great.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because React mainly used for [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). If you want to get more pages then you can use [React router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router)

You will get an overview: https://scotch.io/tutorials/routing-react-apps-the-complete-guide
https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf

Answer (score 0):

I think the only one main HTML page scenario, is the case when your app is a full react app.
There are also cases where the app is only partially 'react'
Here is a good [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31933359/using-react-in-a-multi-page-app) to read.

Hope it helps.